# how to put text right and left in a footer like the one in the image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

Firstly this is my second question in stackoverflow so dont be strict :( .
I am trying to create a template using html,css and sometimes bootstrap
In the footer i want to put text to the right like" terms and conditions,privacy" and in the left the social media icons.

I tried using columns but something was wrong or it does not work that way.

i am not in level 10 reputation so i hope the screenshot will help you understand...More info are that i want the whole template to be centered so i used a class with wrap.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fEIY.png

Comment: add your HTML & CSS code here

Comment: the whole code?

Comment: thanks everyone you helped me all..the only thing now is to add instagram,facebook and twitter icons ...if i find them on the iconfinder do i have to edit them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Bootstrap 4, you can use `float-right` and `float-left` classes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <a href="#" class="text-dark">Terms and conditions</a>
  <a href="#" class="text-dark">Privacy</a>
  <div class="iconHere float-right">
    Follow
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </div>
</section>
```

You can see the full documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/float/).

Comment: please be more precise with your answers. May be you are pointing the right direction but can this be considered as a answer.

Comment: sorry my bad.. i'm already adding a working code to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can just use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` to achieve this.

```css
/* Important things */
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}



/* Decorative */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
}

a + a {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section>
    <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
    <a href="#">Privacy</a>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <a href="#">Follow</a>
    <a href="#">&spades;</a>
    <a href="#">&clubs;</a>
    <a href="#">&hearts;</a>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: that helps too..but i dont want the template to be in javascipt..just html css

Comment: o.0 What are you talking about, there's no javascript in it, the `javascript: void(0)`is just for disabling the link

Comment: oh sorry now i got it..sorry mr hao i am new in programming

Comment: @ChristosDritsas I just updated the answer, it this better? :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide code but this is how you can do it.

There're many ways you could do it, you could use flex-box, or just use positions, or floats like I did below.

```css
.footer{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 15px;
  border: thin solid #d3d3d3;
}
.block{
  display: inline-block; /* important */
}

.shift-right{
  float: right;  /* important */
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="block ">Left Content</div>
  <div class="block shift-right"> Right Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i did not provide code..cause i was in 0 :( . But thank you....i can start from something now..and add the social media icons

Comment: Great. this method will work in almost all browsers including old browsers. You could use Flexbox which is quicker but won't be supported by old browsers.